# itextsharp - change document version

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp, and I need to do following:

1. Open existing pdf
2. Check pdf version
3. If version is not 1.4, change it to 1.4
4. Save changes in same file

Can someone help me with this.

I'm using PDFSharp to create pdf with two pages in one as descrbed here http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=38&Itemid=49 but when I'm trying to this, some PDF's throw me an error *Cannot handle iref streams. The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6.* So I tried with suggested workaround http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=693#p5855 bu it's still doesent working. Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain WHY you want to change the document version. iTextSharp can change the "number", e.g. PDF-1.3 to PDF-1.4 or PDF-1.5 to PDF-1.4, but it won't change anything else. For instance: if you have OCGs (only available in PDF-1.5), changing the version number to 1.4 won't remove those OCGs. Without telling us *the purpose* of changing the version, your question will be downvoted/closed.

Comment: You can easily do two-up pages on a single document with iTextSharp, I'd recommend just using that for the whole process.